# sbt-native-packager with docker output in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have an SBT project with sbt-native-packager 1.0.2 plugin that works fine if I run locally sbt docker:publish. When I do the same thing in Jenkins using the sbt plugin, I get the following error:

```
[info] Step 2 : RUN dnf -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless wget sed ca-certificates openssl 
[info] ---> Running in 1b3918fcffa6 
[info] exec: "dnf -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless wget sed ca-certificates openssl": executable file not found in $PATH 
[info] Removing intermediate container 1b3918fcffa6 
[error] [8] System error: exec: "dnf -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless wget sed ca-certificates openssl": executable file not found in $PATH 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 1 
at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.publishLocalDocker(DockerPlugin.scala:282) 
at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$$anonfun$projectSettings$14.apply(DockerPlugin.scala:100) 
at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$$anonfun$projectSettings$14.apply(DockerPlugin.scala:99) 
at scala.Function4$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function4.scala:35) 
at scala.Function4$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function4.scala:34) 
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47) 
at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40) 
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63) 
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226) 
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226) 
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17) 
at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235) 
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226) 
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226) 
at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159) 
at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
[error] (main/docker:publishLocal) Nonzero exit value: 1
```

I bet the problem is in Jenkins configuration of the $PATH variable but I have no idea how to work around it. I already tried /usr/bin/dnf or both with yum but none works. For /usr/bin/dnf it says it cannot find path /usr/bin/dnf.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your base image? Looks like it cannot find dnf. dnf is a new package manager in fedora. Perhaps the version of fedora on jenkins is too old?

Comment: It's fedora:latest. I get the same error with yum. It works if I run this outside of Jenkins.

Comment: Perhaps latest on that system is out of date?

Comment: I have dockerUpdateLatest := true in my SBT build. The problem is with the $PATH, not yum or dnf or whatever. It cannot find *any* commands at all: [error] [8] System error: exec: "uname -a": executable file not found in $PATH 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 1